# Composer.lock, composer.json workflow and version control

Tags: php, git, version-control, composer-php

I thought the workflow with composer was like this:

1. Define your dependencies and other data in your `composer.json`
2. Run `composer install` or later `composer update`
3. Include `composer.json` and `composer.lock` in your versioned repository
4. After cloning your repository, run `composer install` and you're ready

But, at step 4, when I clone my repository to the remote server and run `composer install` I am getting an error

```
[ErrorException]       
Undefined index: hash
```

A quick search says that I have to delete my `composer.lock`, which is up to date with my local repository. So, what am I doing wrong ? Isn't `composer.lock` there to make sure that both my repositories have the same versions on the included dependencies ? I don't feel like it should be excluded from my repository ...

**UPDATE**
And I see frameworks like OctoberCMS to include composer.lock into their .gitignore. I'm really confused, composer's documentation clearly states that the composer.lock is the one that actually locks your dependencies to the same version, composer.json is just the guidelines on what version to pick.

Comment: Almost correct, generally you don't version `composer.lock`, `composer install` installs from the `.json` IF there is no `composer.lock`, if there is a `.lock` it would mean that an install is already done, and an update is needed.

Comment: @Jelmergu But in the [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) it says:
`Committing this file to VC is important because it will cause anyone who sets up the project to use the exact same versions of the dependencies that you are using.`

Comment: I'm not perfect. In that case I have been doing things wrong, good to know. Still `composer install` would not have to be used in your case, use `composer update` instead

Comment: @Jelmergu But, `composer update` is the same as deleting `composer.lock` and running `composer install` ...

Comment: @Jelmergu - you've got it backwards. `composer update` should only be done when you explicitly *want* to cause your (and everyone else on your team)'s dependencies to be *updated to the latest available ones*. This *overwrites* `composer.lock`. Which you then commit. This might be something you do *rarely*, so that you don't have to be concerned about some breaking change in an upstream library, until you are at a good moment to deal with those. Usually it doesn't matter - breaking changes are rare - but this is the intended principle, according to Composer docs, and most discussions of this.